# Spring batch JobStep is failing when configured with multiple jobs

Tags: java, spring, parallel-processing, spring-batch

I am trying to configure multiple jobs in single context file and run them parallel.Below is the configuration

```
    <batch:job id="ParallelJob" incrementer="runIdIncrementer" restartable="true">
            <batch:split id="parallelprocessing" task-executor="taskExecutor">
                <batch:flow>
                    <batch:step id="ParallelJob.step1" >
                            <batch:job ref="JobA" job-launcher="jobLauncher" job-parameters-extractor="jobParametersExtractor"/>
                    </batch:step>       
                </batch:flow>
                <batch:flow>
                    <batch:step id="ParallelJob.step2" >
                            <batch:job ref="JobB" job-launcher="jobLauncher" job-parameters-extractor="jobParametersExtractor"/>
                    </batch:step>       
                </batch:flow>
            </batch:split>
        </batch:job> 


<batch:job id="JobA" restartable="true">
        <batch:step id="abc">
            <batch:tasklet >
                <batch:chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" processor="processor"  />
            </batch:tasklet>
      </batch:step>

    </batch:job>

<batch:job id="JobB" restartable="true">
        <batch:step id="abc">
            <batch:tasklet >
                <batch:chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" processor="processor"  />
            </batch:tasklet>
      </batch:step>

    </batch:job>
```

I am facing exception saying `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.core.Job] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3:ParallelJob,JobA,JobB`.Can someone help me.Reference http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#split-flows

Comment: Problem is elsewhere. Where are you injecting / using the Job?

Comment: i am not injecting it anywhere else.the above mentioned is only configuration and starting the ParallelJob using commandLineJobRunner.bat classpath:META-INF/spring/batch-context.xml ParallelJob -next %* – @Tunaki

Comment: Could you post the whole stacktrace of the exception. There must be a Bean into which another Bean with a Job-interface has to be injected. An I assumed this injection is not qualified with a name, so Spring does not know which one of the three job beans it should inject.

Answer (score 0):

i am able to fix this.I am injecting Job in one of the classes which i am not using anymore